# Count records between rolling date range in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-columns, calculated-field

I have a file with a **[start]** and **[end]** date in Tableau and would like to create a calculated field that counts number of rows on a rolling basis that occur between [start] and [end] for each **[person]**. This data is like so:

```
| Start   | End     | Person
|1/1/2019 |1/7/2019 | A
|1/3/2019 |1/9/2019 | A
|1/8/2019 |1/15/2019| A
|1/1/2019 |1/7/2019 | B
```

I'd like to create a calculated field **[count]** with results like so:

```
| Start   | End     | Person | Count
|1/1/2019 |1/7/2019 | A      | 1
|1/3/2019 |1/9/2019 | A      | 2
|1/8/2019 |1/15/2019| A      | 2
|1/1/2019 |1/7/2019 | B      | 1
```

**EDITED:** A good analogy for what **[count]** represents is: *"how many videos does each person rented at the same time as of that moment?*" With the 1st row for person A, count is 1, with 1 item rented. As of row 2, person A has 2 items rented. But for the 3rd row  [count]= 2 since the video rented in the first row is no longer rented.

Comment: what do you mean by number of rows? can you elaborate, Also I think sample data is incomplete

Comment: I don't understand why the third row is 2 and not 3?

Comment: @wavery the third row has [start] value after the [end] of row one, but between [start] and [end] of row two. So row two and three both equal 2.

Comment: One solution here is to reshape your data. Instead of a row having (Person, Start, End), each row can be (Person,Start,1) or (Person,End,-1). A running sum along the third column by Person will give you the current number for any date.